# ASP Classic and MSAccess Dates

Tags: database, ms-access, asp-classic

I've entered dates into Access from ASP before and im using the same code...but it will not take the query no matter what.  I've been working all day, maybe im just tired, but can somebody take a look at this for me?

This is a sample query the code generates:

```
INSERT INTO COMMENTS (FID,AUTHOR,DATE,COMMENT) VALUES ("6","John Doe",#4/15/2012#,"test comment")
```

Like I said, the template for the code came directly from somewhere else that works.  If I remove the date from the query, it works fine.  I've triple checked the DATE field is a DATE/TIME column and i've tried removing and re-creating it with no luck.

Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't touched Access in a while, but a few queries you can try:

Query 1: Change `DATE` to `[DATE]` since `DATE` may be a common keyword used by Access.

```
    INSERT INTO COMMENTS 
    (FID,AUTHOR,[DATE],COMMENT) 
    VALUES 
    ("6","John Doe",#4/15/2012#,"test comment")
```

Query 2: Change `#4/15/2012#` to `GetDate()` (Date Stamp)

```
    INSERT INTO COMMENTS 
    (FID,AUTHOR,[DATE],COMMENT) 
    VALUES 
    ("6","John Doe",GETDATE(),"test comment")
```

Or maybe try a combination of them. Report back if either of these don't work.

Comment: Your first example is valid, your second is not. If the OP requires the current date, use Date(), not GETDATE(). Ideally, dates should be in the format 4 digit year, month, day to avoid ambiguity and locale errors. It seems pretty odd to me that a field (column) called FID should be text. If it is numeric, the value should not be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `#MM-DD-YYYY#`. It's also suggested to use YYYY-MM-DD, so you can try `#YYYY-MM-DD#` or even `#'YYYY-MM-DD'#`.

Comment: Date is a reserved word and has to be bracketed as shown by @ZeeTee. See also my comment below regarding date format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got to work for me:

```
    strDSNPath = "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("data.mdb")
    strSQL_Insert = "INSERT INTO COMMENTS (FID,AUTHOR,CDATE,COMMENT) VALUES ('6','John Doe','4/15/2012','test comment')"

   Set Conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Conn.Open strDSNPath
            Conn.Execute strSQL_Insert
        Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing
```

And here's the database: [Download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50750605/WebDesign/data.mdb)

Notes:

*I couldn't get it to work with the (") so I used (')

*The date has no hashtag (which may need fixing)

*Sorry it's so late, it took me like an hour and a half to figure it out, and it only ended up being "use single quotes"

Comment: CDATE is a really bad name for a field (column) it is the name of a function.

Comment: You cannot use double quotes (") within a string, how would the system tell when the string ended and your value began. You can use two double quotes: `" VALUES (""test comment"")"`. If you are using single quotes, and it is to be recommended, you must escape any occurance of single quotes in your string by using two single quotes  : `" VALUES ('I''ll try')"` The replace function will do this.

Comment: Is FID really a text column (field)?

Comment: CDATE: Oh, I didn't know... That'll have to change before the final.
Double quotes: I know, but I was getting "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 4." error until I used single's
FID: It's a number field, i don't know she used it up top...